# API V3 API Explorer Invoice Shipping Charge

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Does anyone have a sample Transaction that can me used to sparse update an invoice's shipping charge via the IPP v3 API Explorer?

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" sparse="true">
    <Id>6</Id>
    <SyncToken>5</SyncToken> 
    <ShipMethodRef>Ground</ShipMethodRef>   
    <ShipDate>01-30-2014</ShipDate>
    <TrackingNum>12345678</TrackingNum>
    <Line>
        <Amount>10.00</Amount>
        <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
        <SalesItemLineDetail>
           <ItemRef>SHIPPING_ITEM_ID</ItemRef>
        </SalesItemLineDetail>
   </Line>
</Invoice>
```

Is it like the QuickBooks SDK where you have to include the line number of the other Lines?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I figured out.
You need all the Line items that are of type SalesItemLineDetail.
It seems easier to just repeat the nodes from your query. You can get by with some minimum values.  I did show the minimum values.  You also need the correct sync token.

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" sparse="true">
    <Id>16</Id>
    <SyncToken>1</SyncToken> 
    <ShipMethodRef>FedEx Ground</ShipMethodRef>   
    <ShipDate>02-03-2014</ShipDate>
    <TrackingNum>12345678901234567890</TrackingNum>
    <Line>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <LineNum>1</LineNum>
        <Description>A widget</Description>
        <Amount>10.00</Amount>
        <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
           <SalesItemLineDetail>
           <ItemRef name="Widget 1">2</ItemRef>
           <TaxCodeRef>NON</TaxCodeRef>
        </SalesItemLineDetail>
     </Line>
     <Line>
        <Amount>10.00</Amount>
        <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
           <SalesItemLineDetail>
               <ItemRef>SHIPPING_ITEM_ID</ItemRef>
         </SalesItemLineDetail>
     </Line>
</Invoice>
```